# got this error 1.4.3 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download when downloading hyperledger fabric samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was facing some error in fabcar and other of hyperledger fabric samples due to removing and installing prerequisites many times. then i **reinstall ubuntu** and **prerequisites** to run hpyerledger fabric. now when i download fabric sample binaries i am getting the following error...

```
===> Checking out v1.4.3 of hyperledger/fabric-samples
HEAD is now at f86ec95 [FAB-16390] Added filter for invalid transactions

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 1.4.3 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.3/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.3.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 1.4.3 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `cat /etc/os-release && curl --version && tar --version && gzip --version` Trying to reproduce this, we tested this change before merging it but we aren't seeing this issue when we run it

Comment: Link to the chat where we solved the issue https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions?msg=r7MfNWnFYdAWTbQ7A